# d3.select.style not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just spent an embarrassing amount of time resolving this error and want to document the answer.

The following bit of code has the desired result on Chrome but not on Firefox:

```
svg=d3.select('svg').style({height : 100,width : 200})
```

Why?

Comment: It's not valid to specify lengths in CSS without units. Report this as a bug to Chrome's bugtracker.

Answer (score 15):

The answer

```
svg=d3.select('svg').style({height : 100 + "px", width : 200 + "px"})
```

Looks like Chrome decides to default to"px" while Firefox want you to be explicit.

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue.